# angular routing with optional parameter not working when refresh f5

Tags: angularjs

I have angular routing:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!").html5Mode(true); 
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', { templateUrl: '/home/index', controller: 'homeCtrl' })    
    .when('/su-kien/:sename?', { templateUrl: function (params) { return typeof (params.sename) != "undefined" ? '/app/main/views/sukien/detail.html?sename=' + params.sename : '/app/main/views/sukien/index.html' }, controller: 'eventCtrl' })  
    .when('/:pagename', { templateUrl: '/app/main/views/common/index.html', controller: 'commonCtrl' })
     .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

I don't know why :pagename it works fine even with f5 refresh the page, /su-kien/:sename? works as well but f5 reload only works for the routing without paramter :sename

e.g:

```
      /abc => /:pagename does the job 
      /su-kien => works well too, f5 ok
      /su-kien/aaaa=> work but f5 doesn't
```

Have a nice weekend.